# 7 Tequilas from 3 Tequilas ( Combination Problem)

Tags: summation, combinations

I was having dinner at a restaurant called 7 tequilas several years ago and I asked the waitress how many tequilas they had... the answer was 3. This bothered my for a long time, but I recently had an epiphany that perhaps 3 tequilas are enough to make 7 distinct mixtures if we ignore proportionality and assume that even though all 3 are tequila, and different brands... that they are different from each-other such that A ≠ B ≠ C where A, B, & C are the three Tequilas.

If I list the combinations I get 7 different combinations:

`A B C,
A B,
A C,
B C,
A,
B, &
C.`

Is there en elegant way to express this sort of problem? The only thing I can think of is:

**THIS** $\sum_{i=1}^3$*Combination of 3 elements choose i*

**OR THIS** *C(3,1)+C(3,2)+C(3,3)*

Also I apologize in advance for errors or lack of convention I've not been in any formal maths for several years. I may need to brush up on combinations. My first instinct was *3!*... but that does not equal 7, so it contradicts the enumerated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simply, each variety is either in the blend, or not, thus $2^3 = 8$ ways

But this includes no drink, thus $8-1=7$

so for $n$ varieties, $2^n -1$ combinations

Answer (score 1):

$$\left[\sum_{r=0}^3\binom 3r\right]-\binom 30=2^3-1=7$$
If there are $n$ brands, then there will be
$2^n-1$ tequila combinations.

Comment: No. It's $2^n-1\neq (n-1)^n-1$. See true blue anil's solution for a clearer explanation.

Comment: But you might no longer know the difference if you try more than 7 combinations in one sitting :)

Comment: Is there a source I can learn why it is always *2^n -1* ? Seems like our combination problem is also a prime-number generator. Is the minus 1 because the last combination is an empty set? -- both answers are correct between hypergeometric, & true blue anil -- I may have to give credit to whomever answered first.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: You can credit both [ :) ] but please feel free to accept true blue anil's solution as it's the more direct one. My solution shows how to arrive at the answer from your workings.